# Create image histogram using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I have a table of 10000 RGB triplets and another table of corresponding colour names. But the number of unique colour names is only 10. Now I want to create a 10-bin histogram for a given image using these two tables. I use NearestNeighbors from scikit-learn for this. Here's part of my code:

```
rgb_matrix = np.asarray(joblib.load('rgb-matrix.pkl'))
rgb_colors = np.asarray(joblib.load('rgb-colors.pkl'))

color_list = []
for i in xrange(len(rgb_colors)):
    color = rgb_colors[i]
    if color not in color_list:
        color_list.append(color)

nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=4,algorithm='ball_tree').fit(rgb_matrix)

rgb_arr = input_image.reshape(-1,3)
color_arr = nbrs.kneighbors(rgb_arr)[1] # No of nearest neighbours is set to 4
color_index = np.asarray(color_arr[:,0]) # Get the top color index

hist = np.zeros(10)
for i in xrange(len(color_index)):
    hist[color_list.index(rgb_colors[color_index[i]])] += 1.0
```

But this loop makes the process really slow. Is there a way I can use np.histogram here?